# My Button for submitting form through jquery-ajax is not working in safari and IE. It is working smooth in chrome and firefox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This code will fetch record from database and store in $result

```
try{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM leads
        LEFT JOIN type_of_lead
        ON leads.lead_type_id = type_of_lead.lead_type_id
        WHERE lead_id = ?"; 
        $stmt  = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($lead_id));
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

HTML :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="post" id="myLeadForm">
    <input type="text" name="street" class="form-control" id="street" value="<?php echo $result['street']; ?>" >
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding:10px 50px;" id="update-lead" value="">Update</button>
</form>
```

Above is form and text form which will display fetch record from database through $result

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#update-lead').click(function(){
        //alert();

        $.ajax
        ({ 
            url: 'update-form.php',
            data: $('#myLeadForm').serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#loading-image").show();
            },
            success: function(result)
            {
                $('#display-area').html(result);
                $("#loading-image").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
    <?php
}catch(PDOException $e) { 
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}?>
```

And above code is ajax call on click event of button with id update-lead

This code works fine in chromr and firefox but it is not working in Safari and IE.

Comment: try with changing button type from `button` to `submit`

Comment: I have other buttons also in the form. And all buttons calls some ajax. So doesn't changing type to submit reload a form? which i dont want.

Comment: use `prevent.default`

Comment: the form is inside a loop or you are only fetching one record from database and showing in form?

Comment: Form is one. But i am fetching many records. One record is just for example here.

Comment: don't use id `$('#update-lead').click(function(){` use class `$('.update-lead').click(function(){` when dealing with dynamic data also change button type to submit and use `
event.preventDefault()` http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: And i tried preventDefault() by put it above $ajax({...}); and below  $('#update-lead').click(function(){.. function. But it didn't worked. is prevent.default is some other stuff you are refering to? or i used it correctly

Comment: Can you specify any technical reason not to use id over class?

Comment: Detail explanation would be truly appreciated as i am newbie here.

Comment: `$('.update-lead').click(function(event){event.preventDefault(); //rest of the code}`

Comment: id's must be unique read here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really

Comment: Thanks Shehary for your kind help. event.preventDefault worked for me after changing the sequence of jquery-ajax calls i have used. Like putting click event of update button at top of all scripts and less prior js below. And It was done using ID only. But thanks for sharing your knowledge regarding differentiate between ID and CLASS.

Comment: You are most welcome